# Why there is no implicit conversion from pointer to reference?

Tags: c++, c++03

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    int* y = &x;
    int& z = y;
    return 0;
}
```

For this code, the compiler gives an error on `int& z = y;` saying:

```
./example.cpp: In function 'int main()':

./example.cpp:7:11: error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

    7 |  int& z = y;

      |           ^

      |           |

      |           int*

./example.cpp:7:11: error: cannot bind rvalue '(int)y' to 'int&'
```

Why? I know why the error, and I know how to fix it, I'm curious to why the compiler is not able to implicitly perform the conversion, when to me it seems trivial my intention, to make the pointer and the reference refer to the same memory location. Are there any corner cases I am missing?

Comment: You have to `int& z = *y;` or `int* &z = y;` if you want reference to the pointer itself.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm curious to why the compiler cannot infer that by itself.

Comment: Because it's not in the standard.

Comment: C++ is retro compatible with C, which has strict pointer operations. It's crucial to distinguish a pointer from  the value pointed by the pointer, so it would lead to many low level errors if the compiler hide that from the programmer. High level languages can do the stuff you say as they are not designed to be pointer operation heavy.

Comment: I know you ask for c++03 but what would you expect for `auto& z = y`? Because that gives you a reference of the pointer. An implicit conversion would cause much more problems (user errors) than it solves.

Comment: In general implicit conversions can hide a lot of bugs. For me it’s a lot better that the compiler throws an error in these cases rather than assumes I know what I’m doing. If I do I have a way of saying “shut up, I know what I’m doing” to the compiler, but the other way wouldn’t be possible.

Comment: The only virtue of this, as far as I can tell, is that it will spare you writing a `*`. Meanwhile, there's a whole lot of work to be done in order to consider how it interacts with other language features like overload resolution. The cost to benefit ratio here is not great at all.

Comment: @Timo I can see why `auto` gives an ambiguous situation, but that doesn't justify why it was not inserted in the standard in first place, when auto was not not in yet.

Comment: You have it backwards. Features in the standard need to be justified to be inserted, not the other way around. *Everything* is excluded by default.

Comment: @mcabreb while I agree with the whole C-compatiblity code, this looks to me a C++ only behaviour, since references are involved. I can't see how C code would have problem.

Comment: would you think `int& x = (int*******)ptr` should equals to `int& x = *******ptr`? if not, then why `int& x = (int*)ptr`? (if yes, then, well, because the one who write the standard don't think so? I guess.)

Comment: An implicit conversion would make it very easy to accidentally dereference a null pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pointer can be null, a reference cannot.

**Note : you can't do that**

```
int* ptr = nullptr;
int& ref = *ptr; // dereferencing a nullptr is UB
```

If C++ allow implicite conversion for reference to pointer it mean than it will implicitely deference a pointer, which can be UB.

Answer (score 5):

C++ has a long history of errors stemming from implicit conversions. Have a look at Stephen Dewhurst's book "C++ Gotchas"; the longest chapter is on conversions. This topic is literally full of pitfalls, and we should be glad that the above must be typed out explicitly. That being said...

> Are there any corner cases I am missing?

Consider an overload set like this:

```
void f(void *n);
void f(int& n);
```

and imaging that pointers implicitly convert to references. The following call

```
int n = 42;

f(&n);
```

would be ambigous, because both conversion would be considered an equivalent fit. This is confusing an unnecessary.

Another example would be references to pointers. Not necessarily something you would do often, but this is valid:

```
int n = 42;
int* ptr = &n;

int*& refToPtr = ptr;
```

With an implicit pointer to reference conversion, the above would compile for

```
int& refToPtr = &n;
```

too, even though you meant something different, and again, being less permissive here is a good thing to prevent such errors.

Comment: I can see the problems here, but I can also feel like they could be caught later. In the first case, an analogous can be constructed using multiple inheritance ([here](https://ideone.com/okyAuo) an example) and the compiler gives an ambiguous call error. In the second case, leaving `m` as `int*&`, so compiling as it does today, would be the way to go since it would not involve an implicit conversion needed by the other interpretation.

Comment: When you compare the ambiguity to the multiple inheritance scenario, I'd argue that it's a good thing to _not_ have more such cases.

Comment: This problem **is already addressed** by C++. For instance you could write two overloads taking `float` and `double`, and pass an `int` to them. Since `int` **implicitly** converts to both `float` and `double` the compiler would: `error: call of overloaded 'fun(int&)' is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 1):

You should think a C++ reference as an alias rather than a pointer. This is different from Java references which looks more like a pointer. Then the compiler message is perfectly clear: the aliased object should be an int and you try to reference an int*.

For more informations about references: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references