# Why does this call to Json::Value::append with a pointer compile?

Tags: c++, jsoncpp

Yesterday I came across a function like this in my team's code, using the jsoncpp library:

```cpp
#include <json/value.h>

Json::Value makeList() {
  Json::Value list(Json::arrayValue);
  list.append(new Json::Value(true));
  return list;
}
```

It came to my attention because using `new` in the call to `list.append` leaks some memory, which can be fixed by simply dropping `new`. However, in debugging this I realized that `Json::Value::append` takes either [a `const Json::Value&`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#a7e49ac977e4bcf59745a09d426669f75) or [a `Json::Value&&`](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#ab723e9957d7b198eb102e8e2afc00e3a). [C++ does not implicitly convert pointers to references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56216201/1175455), so a `Json::Value*` should not be implicitly converted into either of these.

To confirm this, I wrote my own short example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    int x = 4;
};

void printValue(const Foo& f) { std::cout << "The value is " << f.x << ".\n"; }
void printValue(Foo&& f)      { std::cout << "The value is " << f.x << ".\n"; }

int main() {
    printValue(new Foo());
}
```

And indeed, this results in a compilation error:

```
own-example.cpp:12:5: error: no matching function for call to 'printValue'
    printValue(new Foo());
    ^~~~~~~~~~
own-example.cpp:8:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Foo *' to 'const Foo' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
void printValue(const Foo& f) { std::cout << "The value is " << f.x << ".\n"; }
     ^
own-example.cpp:9:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'Foo *' to 'Foo' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
void printValue(Foo&& f)      { std::cout << "The value is " << f.x << ".\n"; }
     ^
```

So, why does the code I found calling `Json::Value::append` compile, while the toy example does not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Json::Value(new Json::Value())` compiles because

- `bool x = new Json::Value();` compiles thanks to C++ rules allowing [implicit conversion from a pointer to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions), and
- `Json::Value` has [a constructor overload](https://open-source-parsers.github.io/jsoncpp-docs/doxygen/class_json_1_1_value.html#a350a31ea4a30d384994b0bc010b17495) that takes a `bool`.

Comment: Ah, interesting — so in the real code I encountered, where we weren't just passing `true` to the `Json::Value` constructor every time, this would have been resulting in a functionality bug as well as a memory leak. Thanks!

Comment: @HarryCutts exactly. Which is why non-copy/move constructors taking a single parameter should *usually* be marked `explicit` to avoid unwanted implicit conversions.  Had the `Json::Value(bool)` constructor been marked `explicit`, then `Json::Value(new Json::Value())` would not have compiled. ([demo](https://ideone.com/VR20Xo))